# How to classify very short text for spend analytics?

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I have a very small description of the item, example below-

- ACCELATOR SHAFT
- ADAPTOR –EGR PIPE & EGR VALVE(125KVA)
- ADAPTOR-EGR COOLER AND VALVE-125 KVA
- ADJUSTING LATCH - ALTERNATOR-125 KVA

Some items are just one word long and maximum number of words in a sentence are around 6.

These items need to be classified into category and a sub category for further spend analysis.

This is a generic problem and many of our clients have similar problems and it takes a lot of time in classifying this manually so we are trying to develop a ML/NLP model to expedite this process.

For problem at hand we have around 2000+ unique items into 6 categories, each category having around 300 items.

We plan to tag around 100 items in each category and expect the model to classify the rest.

- How do we approach the problem, If someone already dealt with such a problem in past, guidance will be helpful
- Does it make sense to go with tokenization/TFIDF approach with such a small description
- What other Neural Network based methods we can look at (LSTM, RNN etc, but will 100 tags per category be sufficient for training)